# How to create server instance in master in nodejs cluster? (both in worker and master)

Tags: node.js

The following code snippet is throwing error. Is there a way to achieve the following functionality ? If not why it is not possible to create server instance in nodejs cluster master?

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

  var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
       cluster.fork();
  }

  // How to create server instance in master?
  // It is throwing error when I create server like below.
  http.Server(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200);
     res.end("hello worlddddd\n");
  }).listen(8000);
} else {
  http.Server(function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);
```

}

Comment: why you need it? if you have 4 cpus, master process will create 4 workers. Another "sever istance" is useless

Comment: My doubt here is If I have 4 cores then 4 workers will be created. Then what is "Master" here? If we are performing any operations on masters like event handlers, then how it will execute? For example I have a Quad-core system . When I console log the processor IDs, there are 4 PIDs for 4 cores and also one more PID is there for master. Where does "Master" come from If I only have 4 cores(then totally I will have 5 instances If I consider "Master", but I have only 4 cores).

Comment: you need a master process to fork your process. If you have 4 core, then you will have 5 process but the first one, the master process, will never do anything. you need it only at start. And for your OS , having 4 core and 5 istances (one of them is master) is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error that I got when running this code seems to point to the address:port combination already being in use.  Change the port that your master server is listening on, and that should resolve the error.