# In node.js cluster what is "Master" ? Where does 5th core come from in the below scenario?

Tags: node.js

If I have 4 cores then 4 workers will be created. Then what is "Master" here? If we are performing any operations on masters like event handlers, then how and where it will execute? For example I have a Quad-core system . When I console log the processor IDs, there are 4 PIDs for 4 cores and also one more PID is there for master. Where does "Master" come from If I only have 4 cores(then totally I will have 5 instances If I consider "Master", but I have only 4 cores).

- What is the purpose of master?
- What are all the oprations performed by the master?
  How can I effectively utilize master?
- Can I do heavy operations in Master?
- In the above scenario can I create server instance in Master, so that I will have total 5 instances?
- Is Master responsible for managing workers?
- If Master event loop is blocked, then will all workers be idle?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? This might be a good start, http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/28/taking-advantage-of-multi-processor-environments-in-node-js/ and then there's obviously the node.js docs.

Comment: Also take a moment to read @Radar155 comment to your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583144/how-to-create-server-instance-in-master-in-nodejs-cluster-both-in-worker-and-m